# When Shiva & Parvati had met for first time and what was the situation?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, parvati

According to Shiva purana, I have found that parvati with her father had went to meet Shiva. It was happened before the kaam dahana. Then how they met with each other and what was the situation. Please describe briefly about it.

Comment: This Q is too broad.. there is a [complete chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226077.html) on this conversation..

Comment: @YDS Hello, I am little confused after seeing ur given link. As per my knowledge, didn't Lord Shiva killed Kaam Deva when he first met Parvati (after penance). Means, he must be very angry that time. Then how that calm discussion can be possible (which shown in link) that time?

Comment: @Rishabh Shiva killed Kama after this episode..See [what Indra said to Kama](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226081.html) "For the sake of gods, at the bidding of her father, Pārvatī is attending on Him, I hear." while sending him to Shiva...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When Shiva & Parvati had met for first time and what was the situation?**

> 1-2. O Nārada, the daughter of the mountain, honoured in the three worlds, was brought up in the palace of Himācala. When she was eight years old, Śiva distressed by Śatī’s separation came to know of her birth. Keeping her wonderful memory within his heart He rejoiced much.
>
> 3. In the meantime, following the conventions of the world, Śiva wished to perform penance in order to concentrate his mind properly. ~**Chapter 11**

Then, Lord Shiva went to Himālaya with his few ganas. When Himācala heard that Shiva came to perform penance in Himālaya he went to meet Lord Shiva with his attendants where Shiva asked him to make arrangements so that none should be able to come near Shiva. Himācala ordered his attendants not to go to the place where Shiva was performing penance.

Later on, Himācala approached Shiva along with his daughter and mentally dedicated Parvati to Shiva. He asked permission of Shiva to visit him daily along with Parvati on which Shiva said:

> Lord Śiva said:—
>
> 24. “O mountain, you shall come every day to see me, leaving your daughter in your abode. Otherwise I cannot be seen”
>
> Himācala said:—
>
> 26. “Let this be kindly mentioned why this girl cannot accompany me here. Is she unworthy of your service? I do not know the reason
>     thereof.”
>
> Śiva said:—
>
> 29. A woman is a phase of illusion. As the scholars who have mastered the Vedas say particularly, a young damsel is a hindrance to ascetics. ~**Chapter 12**

After Shiva's reply, Parvati also asked several questions and Shiva answered which are mentioned in [Śiva-Pārvatī dialogue (Chapter 13)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226077.html).

---

**Source**: [Shiva Purana: Rudra-saṃhitā: Pārvatī-khaṇḍa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226064.html): Chapter 11 - Chapter 13